# How to tell mathpazo to render a correct superscript minus symbol?

Tags: symbols, mathpazo, stix2

I found that the `mathpazo` which I have used since an eternity renders the superscript minus symbols used by `stix2` into asteriks. Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{scrbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{stix2}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\heterozyg}{$^{+/-}$}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\minuszyg}{$^{-/-}$}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\gs}{$\rightwhitearrow$}
\begin{document}
    (\gs Shh\heterozyg)
    (\gs Shh\minuszyg) 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Since I would like the arrow symbol from `stix2` I do not have an easy solution. How to adapt this?

Comment: you shouldn't mix two math setup packages. Either use stix2 or mathpazo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't want to load both `mathpazo` and `stix2`, because the latter sets up different font encodings for math fonts and messes them up.

You want instead to use the special arrow as a text symbol. How to do it?

We find `\stix@MathSymbol{\rightwhitearrow}{\mathord}{arrows1}{"EF}` in `stix2.sty`. So let's look for `arrows1` and we find

```
\DeclareSymbolFont{arrows1}{LS1}{stix2sf}{m}{n}
```

OK, we need the `LS1` encoding and we find

```
\DeclareFontEncoding{LS1}{}{}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{LS1}{stix2}{m}{n}
```

That's all we need.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{mathpazo}

\DeclareFontEncoding{LS1}{}{}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{LS1}{stix2}{m}{n}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\textrightwhitearrow}{%
  {\usefont{LS1}{stix2sf}{m}{n}\symbol{"EF}}%
}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\heterozyg}{$^{+/-}$}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\minuszyg}{$^{-/-}$}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\gs}{\textrightwhitearrow}

\begin{document}

(\gs Shh\heterozyg)
(\gs Shh\minuszyg)

\end{document}
```

[image]

You probably should load `newpxtext` and `newpxmath`, which also provide Palatino fonts and are actively maintained, but that doesn't really matter as far as the code above is concerned.

Answer (score 3):

This seems to be an interaction between `stix2` and `mathpazo` using different 8-bit encodings.  The `mathpazo` package by itself does not have this problem unless `stix2` is also loaded:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{scrbook}
\tracinglostchars=3
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\heterozyg}{$^{+/-}$}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\minuszyg}{$^{-/-}$}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\gs}{$\Rightarrow$}
\begin{document}
    (\gs Shh\heterozyg)
    (\gs Shh\minuszyg) 
\end{document}
```

[image: Pazo sample]

If you can use LuaTeX or XeTeX, you can cut that Gordian knot by changing to Unicode fonts.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{scrbook}
\tracinglostchars=3
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\heterozyg}{$^{+/-}$}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\minuszyg}{$^{-/-}$}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\gs}{$\rightwhitearrow$}
\begin{document}
    (\gs Shh\heterozyg)
    (\gs Shh\minuszyg) 
\end{document}
```

[image: TeX Gyre Pagella Math sample]

If you stick with PDFTeX, you probably have to import only the specific symbols you want from `stix2`, not the entire package.  You could also try loading `\usepackage{newpxtext, newpxmath}`, an updated 8-bit version of `mathpazo` that has more symbols.

Comment: +1. I actually tried the `\usepackage{newpxtext, newpxmath}` idea, but it has the same problem as `mathpazo` does.

Comment: @Mico You would take out `stix2` and use a `newpxmath` arrow instead. You only get the problem when you mix the packages.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you switch to `\textsuperscript` text-mode directives.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{scrbook}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % that's the default nowadays
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{stix2}
\usepackage{mathpazo}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\heterozyg}{\textsuperscript{+/-}} 
\DeclareRobustCommand{\minuszyg}{\textsuperscript{-/-}}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\gs}{$\rightwhitearrow$}

\begin{document}
(\gs Shh\heterozyg) (\gs Shh\minuszyg) 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I like this solution since it does not interfere with pathpazo and, as it turne out, with xymtex which I would not dare to touch. Too complex.

Comment: One can even use the -- instead of - resulting in more pronounced minus symbols and as large as the plus ones.

Comment: this avoids the problem in this expression by using text mode, but still leaves all math broken as both packages are still loaded.

Comment: @bkleine - Please unaccept my answer and accept [egreg's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/628838/5001) instead. Thanks.